# Some Problems in a power amplifier circuit with THS3091

Tags: current, spectrum-analyzer, harmonics

Recently, I designed a power amplifier circuit with THS3091. 
The schematic diagram and PCB of the circuit are just the same as the layout example of the datasheet of THS3091 in page 39. But some values of the resistance are not available in my lab. So the modified circuit is this:
[THS3091 schematic diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC0Zr.png)

When I tested the circuit, there are some problems:

1. The frequency of the input signal is 100 kHz. I tested the output signal with the spectrum analyzer. But there are some strange frequencies, such as 0 and -100 kHz. And the value of power at -100 kHz is the same as the value at 100 kHz. What are the strange frequencies mean?
2. The circuit is designed with dual power supply. And the current value of the source is 14 mA, 17 mA with no input signal. If the input signal connected to the circuit, when I increase the peak voltage of the signal slowly, the current value of the source will increase within a certain range, then decrease gradually. However, at last, the current value is smaller than 14 mA, 17 mA, which is strange. I wonder why the current value changes like this.
3. THS3091 is a current feedback amplifier.How to calculate the gain of this kind of circuit?
4. When I increase the peak voltage of the signal slowly, the output signal will distort. And the harmonic will also change, for example, the second harmonic is larger than the third harmonic firstly, then the third harmonic is larger than the second harmonic. Is there any rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Then you're obviously not used to using a spectrum analyzer. On a SA 0 Hz is DC so that means you have a DC offset or biasing voltage at the output.

You can ignore the peak at -100 kHz, it is a result of how the SA cannot distinguish between negative and positive frequencies with your signal. Which is to be expected. Read [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_frequency) for an explanation about negative frequencies.

2) This is very likely related to the operation of the output stage of the opamp. A class AB stage might exhibit this behavior.

3) Same as with the normal voltage feedback amplifier. The inputs are low-impedance and the opamp will try to make **current** flowing through the inputs **zero**. So in your schematic the gain is determined by R3 and R4.

4) I advise you to also look at the signal using an oscilloscope, when the signal distorts the peaks of the sine wave are "cut off" (clipping). Some other non-linear behavior might occur as well. Such distorted sinewaves contain higher order harmonics. It depends on the shape of the wave what the relative power of the harmonics will be relative to the fundamental (the 100 kHz in this case). The [Fourier transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) describes and explains this.

Comment: I used a DC-block to isolate the DC offset. But there was still a value at 0Hz. I think it might be caused by the spectrum analyzer itself. Is there any possibility?

Comment: An ideal spectrum analyser will show no signal at DC after a DC block. A real spectrum analyser will always show an output at 0Hz, the size of which depends on how hard they've worked to minimise it. If they've been lazy, it could be as high as top of screen (TOS), in which case it's damaging the dynamic range for processing other signals. -20dB(TOS) is usually adequate to avoid this. A 'good' level would be -40dB(TOS).

Comment: *But there was still a value at 0Hz* On a SA, "a value" means little as the scale is in dBm so logarithmic. SAs are not good at DC and the value also depends on proper calibration. So I would not worry about it too much.

Answer (score 3):

The circuit modifications you have made are trivial, and should not result in any radically different behaviour. However the ratio of the gain setting resistors is different, so you should expect a slightly different gain.

1) That is an artifact of the way the spectrum analyser works. In order to ensure it goes at least to DC, it is programmed to go some way 'below'. -100k is the same as 100k for 'real' signals.

2) Supply currents, especially under signal conditions, are only nominal.

3) Same as for a voltage feedback amplifier, R4/R3

4) Odd and even harmonics tend to behave differently as they are generated by different mechanisms. It's usual to observe this sort of behaviour.

Comment: 1) So 0Hz (DC) is inside the spectrum analyzer, and has nothing to do with the circuit or the signal or power supply? Does -100k have no real mean? The power value at 100k is the real value, instead of only a half, and another half is -100k?
2）I used to hold that product of supply current and supply voltage is the power that the source supplies. And the supply current will change with change of the input signal. Is that true?

Comment: 3) The modified circuit is this:[modified circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RA2q.png). And the signal inputs from the negative port. Do you mean that the way calculating the gain is the same no matter that the amplifier is CFB or VFB?
4) Is there any rule that odd and even harmonics behave differently?

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer point (4), the others have been adequately covered...

Observe the clipping waveform on a scope. You'll see that one peak starts clipping before the other - that's when the 2nd harmonic (2HD) increases.

Later, when both peaks clip, 3HD predominates.

If you adjust DC bias until both peaks clip at the same level, you'll eliminate the 2HD. There's nothing you can do about the 3HD except use higher supply voltage, which probably means a different amplifier.

Comment: 1) I also designed a load sharing circuit[load sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMORC.png), as the reference circuit in the datasheet of THS3091 in page 33. Is this circuit a way to eliminate 2HD ? What about a push-pull circuit? 
2) To eliminate 3HD, by saying "higher supply voltage", do you mean increasing the supply voltage of the source, or increasing peak voltage of the input signal?